# Is this an equivalent definition of singular cardinal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

In my textbook *Introduction to Set Theory*, the authors define **singular cardinal** as follows:

> [image]

I propose an equivalent definition as follows:

> An infinite cardinal $\kappa$ is called **singular** if there exists an increasing sequence of ordinals $\langle \alpha_\nu \mid \nu<\vartheta \rangle$ such that $\vartheta\neq\kappa$ is a limit ordinal and $\kappa=\lim_{\nu\to\vartheta}\alpha_\nu$.

Next I prove that my proposed definition implies one by the authors:

> 1. $\alpha_\nu<\kappa$ for all $\nu<\vartheta$
>
> If not, there exists $\nu'<\vartheta$ such that $\alpha_{\nu'}\ge\kappa$. Since $\vartheta$ is a limit ordinal, $\nu'+1<\vartheta$. Since $\langle \alpha_\nu \mid \nu<\vartheta \rangle$ is increasing, $\alpha_{\nu'+1}>\alpha_{\nu'}\ge\kappa$. Then $\kappa=\lim_{\nu\to\vartheta}\alpha_\nu \ge \alpha_{\nu'+1}>\kappa$, which is a contradiction.
>
> 2. $\vartheta<\kappa$
>
> If not, $\kappa < \vartheta$ and thus $\kappa+1 < \vartheta$. Since $\langle \alpha_\nu \mid \nu<\vartheta \rangle$ is increasing, $\alpha_\nu \ge \nu$  for all $\nu<\vartheta$. It follows that $\alpha_{\kappa+1}>\alpha_\kappa\ge \kappa$. Then $\kappa=\lim_{\nu\to\vartheta}\alpha_\nu \ge \alpha_{\kappa+1}>\kappa$, which is a contradiction.

Could you please verify my attempt? Thank you so much!

Comment: I do not recogize the author's definition.  It is weirdly complex.  The usual definition of singular cardinal is not equal to its cofinality.  $\omega_{\omega_0}$ for example.

Comment: Hi @WilliamElliot, my textbook introduces *cofinality* right after *singular cardinal*.

Comment: Where do you think you might be wrong in your proof? (I haven't read it, but I would be happy to read a specific part of it if necessary.)